# How to build a Intel XDK project from command line?

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

While Cordova and PhoneGap projects can be built with command line tools, I don't know if the same is possible for Intel XDK. I'd like to automate environment switch (development/acceptance/production) with some scripts. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the XDK does not support a command-line driven build system. The build system "lives" in the cloud and does not provide an API that is accessible locally. If you have some specific APIs you'd like to have access to, and can list them, I can provide this as feedback to the engineering team.

Comment: My only limitation is not being able to upload my source code to the cloud, build it on some platform, and download the binaries without the IDE assistence. I don't need, for instance, the download of previous builds.

Comment: Okay, I'll let the engineering group know of that need. No promises that it will show up. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @xmnboy what's the status of this? Is there a link to an issue tracker you can share?

Comment: We don't maintain a public issue database for the XDK. The tool was not designed to provide a CLI interface, like PhoneGap Build does. Despite that, we have made significant improvements in the compatibility with the standard Cordova CLI project, so you could do builds locally (assuming, of course, your system supports the desired build targets). Sorry I can't promise anything like a PhoneGap CLI.